# Double dot syntax in JavaScript - What is this expression doing and how is it valid syntax?

Tags: javascript

```
    14.toString();
    // Result -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

    14..toString();
    // Result -> "14"
```

What is placing an extra dot after the number doing, and how is this valid syntax?

Comment: This Question has answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211093/1787416

Comment: Related: [Why 42.toString() fails in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398347/why-42-tostring-fails-in-js)

Comment: @AntoKing That question has *nothing* to do with this one...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Who unmarked this as a duplicate?  This question is a direct duplicate of the one I posted NOT the one AntoKing posted...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are high enough rep to see who did it though.  This is a clear duplicate

Comment: @PWKad [Quentin did](http://i.imgur.com/AZ8PkJ9.png), presumably to let it be re-closed as a dupe of the right thing.

Comment: I looked at the questions it had been marked as a duplicate of, one of them looked related, but not actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

`14.` is a Number. `.toString()` calls a method on that Number.

Thus `14..toString()` is the same as `14.0.toString()`.

You couldn't have `14.toString()` because the `.` is still the floating point and not the property accessing symbol.

Comment: nitpick: `14.` is a `number`, not a `Number`; `.toString` autoboxes it

Answer (score 3):

It is important to remember that the parser is greedy.

It sees the `1`, so it starts reading a number. `4` is valid in a number, `.` is valid in a number, `t` is not, so it stops.

So it has the number `14.` (which is just `14`). Now what to do with it? Uh... there's a `t` there, that's not valid, ERROR!

---

In the second case, `.` is valid in a number, `.` would be valid but we already have a dot so stop there.

We have `14.` again, but this time when looking what to do it sees `.`, so it converts the `14.` to a `Number` object, then calls `toString()` on it, result `"14"`

---

See also: [Why does "a + + b" work, but "a++b" doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491915/why-does-a-b-work-but-ab-doesnt/7491967#7491967)

Comment: Of course, you should never be seeing this code "in real life". Just write `"14"` if it's a string that you want.

Comment: I'm thinking pretty much the only valid use case would be calling `toLocaleString`: `1400000000..toLocaleString()` in my locale is `"1,400,000,000"` but for some other locales it would be `"1.400.000.000"`.