# Understanding Maximal Munch in Java?

Tags: java, javac

I know [Maximal Munch Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) isn't `Java` specific, but my question only concerns `Java` and `Java compiler`.

I've also read some of the related answers:

- [Why doesn't a+++++b work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341202/why-doesnt-ab-work-in-c)
- [Why does “a + + b” work, but “a++b” doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491915/why-does-a-b-work-but-ab-doesnt)

But I'm still not able to fully grasp the concept of *Maximal Munch* and its applications.

Like in the following code:

```
int i = 3;
int j = +i;
System.out.println(i); //3
System.out.println(j); //3
```

How is the statement `int j = +i;` interpreted by the `Java compiler` and why this works?

Another example, `int j = + +i;` also works, but I'm not sure how.

I tried to understand this concept on my own, but I'm not able to.

I would like to know how this works, the concept behind it and how the `Java compiler` treats such statements.

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign can be used as:

- `1 + 2` binary numeric addition operator
- `"A" + "B"` binary string concatenation operator
- `++i` unary increment operator
- `+i` unary positive sign operator (uncommon, the `-i` unary negation sign operator is more common)

Since a positive sign operator doesn't actually *do* anything, it can be eliminated.

```
// All the same
int j = + +i;
int j = +i;
int j = i;
int j = +(+(i));
int j = +(i);
```

See here for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the unary plus operator, indicating a positive value. Frankly, it's quite pointless - `+i` is the same as `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this section on lexical translations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) from the Java Language Specification:

> **The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.** There is one exception: if lexical translation occurs in a type context (§4.11) and the input stream has two or more consecutive `>` characters that are followed by a non-`>` character, then each `>` character must be translated to the token for the numerical comparison operator `>`.
>
> *The input characters `a--b` are tokenized (§3.5) as `a`, `--`, `b`, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` could be part of a grammatically correct program.*

So in your case:

```
int j = +i;
```

is tokenized into:

- `int`
- `j`
- `=` (the assignment operator)
- `+` (the unary plus operator indicating a positive value)
- `i`

`int j = + +i;`

is tokenized into:

- `int`
- `=`
- `j`
- `+` (the unary plus operator indicating a positive value)
- another unary plus operator `+`
- `i`

The two statements are therefore exactly the same as `int j = i` since all `+` operators are interpreted as the unary plus (no additive `+` or increment `++`).